# Using PHP to write git hooks

Tags: php, windows, git, hook

I want to use PHP writing git hooks but have some problem.
I use Windows 7 LAMP packet and git bash.
So, if I run the next script (**pre-commit** hook) through git shell:

https://gist.github.com/713716

it works fine and there is **123** on the screen. But if I use:

```
git commit
```

I have the next error:

```
error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory
```

So, what the problem is?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line? webpage? what user is running the script? is it the Apache/Nobody user?

Comment: This is Windows 7 which have no web server users. Using via CLI interface.

Comment: Sorry I thought you said LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, P[hp, erl, ython]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely work on Windows systems but it might have something to do with either making sure the pre-commit file is executable by every user (per Phil's comment), or something to do with git invoking a php command.

Looks like [this problem may exist elsewhere but not easily reproduceable](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=533).

It's janky, but it might work if you create a new file somewhere with a php extension and invoke that file from the pre-commit hook.

```
#pre-commit
C:/WebServers/usr/local/php5/php C:/path/to/123.php
#123.php
<?php echo 123 ?>
```